# nginx + phpmyadmin - Stuck after login page all blank and token in the url

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, hhvm

I have an ubuntu 14.04 server with

**Nginx + HHVM (instead of php) + mariadb** and I just installed phpmyadmin

All the setup seems fine and my host/phpmyadmin works alright but whenever i try to login with my mysql credentials i get stuck after login in a blank page and something like this in the url:
**phpmyadmin/index.php?token=7e858f9ed3b783b34d4c2274d721f125&SID**

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-lemh-stack-in-ubuntu/) tutorial for installing everything that you need. Maybe it  could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue ... 
If you recently updated your php, check if the mcrypt extension is enabled or not !

(Mcrypt is not available on php7.2, if you want to enable it, you have to create a symlink from the 7.1 folder)